# How can I move an image in reference of canvas after rotating

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a canvas, where an image can be moved and rotated. The image should be always rotated around the center of the canvas (not the center of the image).

I got most of it working, but somehow, when the image is moved after it was already rotated, the image is not moved in the same direction of the mouse but rather in direction of the rotation and the mouse combined.

I did quite a lot of research but couldn't figure out yet, can anyone help me here?

This is the code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const slider = document.getElementById('slider')

let isDown = false
let startCoords = []
let lastTransform = [0,0]
let degrees = 0


slider.oninput = function(e) {
  degrees = e.target.value
  drawOnCanvas()
    
  }

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDown = true;
  startCoords = [
    e.offsetX - lastTransform[0],
    e.offsetY - lastTransform[1]
  ];
}

document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    isDown = false;
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if(!isDown) return;
    lastTransform = [e.offsetX - startCoords[0], e.offsetY - startCoords[1]];
    drawOnCanvas();
}

function drawOnCanvas() {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  let scale = 0.3
  let image = new Image()
  image.src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3400764/pexels-photo-3400764.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
  
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    ctx.save()

    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2)
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180)
    ctx.translate(lastTransform[0], lastTransform[1])
    ctx.scale(scale, scale)
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width/2,-image.width/2)
    ctx.restore()
  })
}

drawOnCanvas()
```

And here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nt5zo2g/)

Comment: My suggestion is whenever you want to move it, unrotate it first, translate the canvas, and then rotate it again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @programmerRaj! Could you give me an example, how exactly I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you are adjusting the scale and rotation. They seem to be constant values (always a sale of 0.3 and 0 degree rotation).

Comment: Sorry, in the linked jsfiddle I had the working code, but I updated it here as well. Dragging the image and rotating is an issue, I left out the scaling for now, to keep it less complex... Does it make sense like that?

Comment: Yes, I can understand how your user can change the translate now. When you call `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()`, are you saving a completely untransformed transformation?